# Smaller block size for more intense jobs Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Does it make to use smaller blocks for jobs that perform more intense tasks?

For example, in Mapper I'm calculating the distance between two signals, which may take some time depending on the signal length, but on the other hand my dataset size is currently not so big. That takes me into temptation to specify smaller block size (like 16MB) and to increase the number of nodes in cluster. Does that make sense?

How should I perform? And if it is ok to use smaller blocks, how to do it? I haven't done it before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether that makes sense to do for your job can only really be known by testing the performance.  There is an overhead cost associated with launching additional JVM instances, and it's a question of whether the additional parallelization is given enough load to offset that cost and still make it a win.

You can change this setting for for a particular job rather than across the entire cluster.  You'll have to decide what's a normal use case when deciding whether to make this a global change or not.  If you want to make this change globally, you'll put the property in the XML config file or Cloudera Manager.  If you only want to do it for particular jobs, put it in the job's configuration.

Either way, the smaller the value in `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize`, the more mappers you'll get (it defaults to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`).  That will work for any InputFormat that uses block size to determine it's splits (most do, since most extend FileInputFormat).

So to max out your utilization, you might do something like this

```
long bytesPerReducer = inputSizeInBytes / numberOfReduceTasksYouWant;
long splitSize = (CLUSTER_BLOCK_SIZE > bytesPerReducer) ? CLUSTER_BLOCK_SIZE : bytesPerReducer);
job.getConfiguration.setLong("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize", splitSize);
```

Note that you can also increase the value of `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize` to reduce the number of mappers (it defaults to 1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is well formed. The problem is that I'm having a very small dataset for testing my algorithm (35MB) and the processing lasts for a couple of hours. The processing is intense (there is a number of steps and iterations) and I know that there is an overhead in case of small data, but I'm a bit worried a bit. So, what would you recommend me to do, if you have more experience with it? The data will (hopefully) be much larger, but would you recommend having a block size of 16MB or something like that, for my problem? Thanks

Comment: If you set the block size to 16, there will only be 2 or 3 mappers for your test data. You'd probably want more than that to make a dent in the performance. But if your data is expected to grow substantially beyond your test size, I think this won't scale and needs fundamental changes, not simple performance tweaks. You need to see if your code can be optimized (perhaps even the algorithm fundamentally altered), or go with an entirely different approach (like [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/), which excels at iterative algorithms and eventually will likely replace MapReduce anyway).

Comment: There are a few other tweaks you could make (like adjusting YARN settings to make sure enough mappers can run in parallel to take full advantage of your hardware, and making sure speculative execution is off so there are no duplicate tasks), but I don't think these tweaks are gonna cut it, given those numbers. You could also throw more hardware at it, but that's a fool's errand when the solution fundamentally doesn't scale.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll think about it. Last question - "But if your data is expected to grow substantially beyond your test size", but what if the size of the data is only a few gigs (2GB, 3GB, 10GB)? I think that in that case it makes sense to have smaller blocks (32MB, or 16MB), since this is sort of "scaled down Hadoop" - size of the data is not large, so it makes sense to have smaller blocks? Namenode will have the same job as in case of 100GB and 64MB, so this seems reasonable, right?

Comment: By the way, the algorithm seems to be pretty scalable, IMHO, but calculations per record are intensive, that's something I cannot improve, at least I think.

Comment: Only you can judge that. My only point was even with linear performance (which you don't always get), 3GB is about 100x larger than your test, and so might take 100x as long (maybe better, depending on your job, but certainly substantially longer). Is it acceptable to take days/weeks processing? Or to add 100x the hardware?

Comment: It's absolutely not unreasonable to set a lower split size, and you shouldn't fear doing so. One of my jobs had like 30GB of input, and the split was set to 10MB. What makes sense depends on the hardware available. If your nodes are already maxed out, adding more splits will probably lower performance.